# Can I Make Entity Models Singular After Import in Database First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity

I have been using the Entity Framework, database first design for sometime now which means I've got many references to hundreds of Entity models in code that have been imported based on the name of the database table, of which some are singular and others are plural.

I would like to use the built in function that Entity allows when importing models to automatically make these models singular or plural in code regardless of the database table name however that function only seems to be work when adding NEW models.

**QUESTION:**

I don't want to have to delete all of my Entity Models and re-import because then my code wouldn't match up to a model without manually changing the many references to those objects. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

If anyone is unsure of what I'm referring to:

[image: Entity update wizard]

Comment: Even if EF could do this (it can't) it wouldn't change all references in your code. This is going to be a lot of manual refactoring. Perfect moment to get rid of the EDMX altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity Framework does not provide this refactoring functionality.

I ended up removing all models and reading them into my project with the proper naming scheme and then manually refactored all references to the models in code.